# Apply multiple transformations to view

Tags: c++, ios, matrix, opengl-es, transformation

I am working on a OpenGL ES application using C++. I run the code on iOS with a few wrapper Obj-c classes that enable me to use gestures (like pan, pinch, rotation).

I use orthographic projection. The code only draws a simple quad for now, and I want to be able to apply any transformations to it using user gesture. That means move it, zoom in and out, rotate (some other derived gestures, like zoom using double-tap etc.).

I thought it will be fine if I simply store origin, scale and angle floats and construct Matrix using each of these, then multiply. That works for simple translation and scale, however, I can't rotate around any point. Now I can't figure out what do I need to be able to rotate around some point, translate, rotate some more around different point.

Here is example how I initialize my matrix

```
Mat4 Mat4::translation(float tx, float ty)
{
    float a[16] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, tx, ty, 0, 1 };
    return Mat4(a);
}

Mat4 Mat4::rotation(float angle)
{
    float a[16] = { cosf(angle), sinf(angle), 0, 0, -sinf(angle), cosf(angle), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    return Mat4(a);
}
```

**How can I apply any number of transformations to 2D view in OpenGL(ES), using matrices? These transformations are caused by gestures (pan, pinch, rotate). For pinch and rotation, I know amount and center point in screen coordinates.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem boils down to finding out with respect to which reference frame you define your transformations.

In practice, you can specify any trasformation (i.e. translation and rotation in 3D) as a 4x4 matrix, like you've done in your example. If they are defined with respect to the current pose of the object, then you can apply a new one by multiplying the new matrix on the right. If they are specified with respect to a fixed reference frame (e.g. your screen origin which does not move) then you pre-multiply them.

Say you apply two rotations, defined by T_rot_1 and T_rot_2

If transformations are defined wrt reference frame attached to the object:

```
T_final_wrt_fixed = T_rot_1_wrt_obj * T_rot_2_wrt_obj
```

If transformations are defined wrt reference to fixed frame:

```
T_final_wrt_fixed = T_rot_2_wrt_fixed * T_rot_1_wrt_fixed
```

For more info, check out [these slides](http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/education/5HC99/wiki/images/7/70/Introduction_Robotics_lecture1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Rotation around arbitrary point is done by translation of the point to origin, rotation around origin and then translating back.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already know this, but what if I need to do this again later on. Should I save the result of this operation in a matrix and later multiply it with another rotation? I don't know whether that will work.